# Mechanize parser working with one variable but not with array

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, mechanize

I'm sending the following to populate a search box on a site through mechanize.

```
@codes = ['123', '456']
```

This is my mech code:

```
@codes.each do |x|
  mech = Mechanize.new
  aliases = ['Linux Mozilla', 'Mac Firefox', 'Mac Mozilla', 
   'Windows Mozilla', 'Linux Firefox', 'Mac Safari', 'Linux Konqueror']
  aliases.shuffle!
  mech.user_agent_alias = "#{aliases[0]}"
  mech.get('http://www.a_url.com')
  mech.page.forms[0]["field-keywords"] = "#{x}"
  mech.page.forms[0].submit
  try = mech.page.link_with(:text => "Product Details").click
  url = try.parser
```

When it gets to here, it works with one code, but breaks with more than one code from `@codes`:

```
match_on = "colorImages': "
end_on = ", "
pic_1 = /#{match_on}.*?#{end_on}/m.match(url).to_s
```

Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.. It was how I passed string variables and not the parser or Mech.